# How can I recover my clash of clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing Clash of Clans perfectly fine up until as recent as last night, when I opened my account it had just started all over again, all my progress was gone.

I cant sign in with the Google account. I was using a blue-stacks on my computer (Windows 7 PC).

**How can I recover my account?**

- Name MARC
- Level 22
- Trophies 871
- Clan named CLASHER.PH